# UNSUPPORTED_PAYEE_CURRENCY error on paypal (unsupported payee currency)

Tags: paypal

Paypal is showing UNSUPPORTED_PAYEE_CURRENCY eventhough the currency passed is "USD". The payments were working without any issue until today.

COuld not find any help on Paypal community forum and the merchant support call isn't connecting.

Let me know if any additional info is needed.

Edit:

This is the request sent:

```
PayPal\Api\Payment Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [redirect_urls] => PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [return_url] => http://xxxx.xxx/cart/paypalApiResponse [cancel_url] => http://xxxx.xxx/cart/paypalFailedOrder ) ) [intent] => sale [payer] => PayPal\Api\Payer Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [payment_method] => paypal ) ) [transactions] => Array ( [0] => PayPal\Api\Transaction Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [amount] => PayPal\Api\Amount Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [total] => 29.00 [currency] => USD ) ) [description] => 95997 [related_resources] => Array ( ) ) ) ) [id] => XXX-XXXXXXXX [state] => created [create_time] => 2017-10-08T15:53:32Z [links] => Array ( [0] => PayPal\Api\Links Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [href] => https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/XXX-XXXXXXX [rel] => self [method] => GET ) ) [1] => PayPal\Api\Links Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [href] => https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=XX-XXXXX [rel] => approval_url [method] => REDIRECT ) ) [2] => PayPal\Api\Links Object ( [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PayPalModel:private] => Array ( [href] => https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/XXX-XXXXX/execute [rel] => execute [method] => POST ) ) ) ) )
```

This goes to a page: https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/fallback?product=ec&fallback=1&reason=UNSUPPORTED_PAYEE_CURRENCY&token=XX-XXXXX

And then redirects to a "Unknown Error" page as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7viWA.png

Comment: Please post your request and response

Comment: @PP_GOPSMTS_KevinG edited the question and included the request and the page it goes to. No response comes back. Just goes to fail page when the user clicks on "go back to merchant".